# How to speak about creating non repeating combinations from lists of binary choices

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I have a pretty basic problem in which I need to combine each item of `a` with each of `b` and `c` where a,b, and c have boolean values.  For example:

`a = [a is on, a is off]`

`b = [b is on, b is off]`

`c = [c is on, c is off]`

I need to combine such that i get all combinations

`a is on, b is on, c is on`

`a is on, b is on, c is off`

`a is on, b is off, c is on`

`a is on, b is off, c is off`

`a is off, b is on, c is on`

and so on.

I thought this was called the quadratic product, but that doesn't show up in google searches.  I can't help but think this is a common mathematical operation, I just don't have the vocabulary for it.  What is it called and how might i go about learning how to generate these combinations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the **multiplication principle**. You can think of this as all of the function $$f:\{a,b,c\}\longrightarrow \{0,1\}$$ This is denoted by $$\{0,1\}^{\{a,b,c\}}$$ and has cardinality $2^3.$ Notice that the sets match the numbers.
 If you are coding, which might be the scenario you are dealing with, i would recommend taking a look at **binary expansions**. This are all of the numbers from $0$ to $7$ written down in binary form. i.e., $000$ represents 0, $001$ represents $1$ and so on.